# How to see the number of visitors on my flask application?

Tags: python, flask

I have created a web application using flask and including a A Relational Database System. I have created a simple admin page. The application has a CV in html and pdf. In my admin page i need to see how many times the CV has been viewed and downloaded or even the names of users that are in the database that have viewed it. this info needs to be shown on the admin page. I was told that a simple query and pagination would be suitable? I have no idea of the code i should use, although the more simple the better.  This is my models.py and routes, is there a simple way i could add something in here?
routes.py

```
@app.route('/admin')
@login_required
def admin():
    if not current_user.is_admin:
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    return "this is admin site"
```

models.py

```
@login.user_loader
def load_user(id):
return User.query.get(int(id))

followers = db.Table('followers',
db.Column('follower_id', db.Integer, ``db.ForeignKey('user.id')),
db.Column('followed_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id')))

  class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), index=True, unique=True)
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(128))
    is_admin =db.Column(db.Boolean(), default = False)
    posts = db.relationship('Post', backref='author', lazy='dynamic')

def set_password(self, password):
    self.password_hash = generate_password_hash(password)
def check_password(self, password):
    return check_password_hash(self.password_hash, password)
def __repr__(self):
    return '<User {}>'.format(self.username)
def avatar(self, size):
    digest = md5(self.email.lower().encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
    return 'https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/{}?d=identicon&s={}'.format(digest, size)
    about_me = db.Column(db.String(140))
    contact_me = db.Column(db.String(140))
    phone = db.Column(db.String(12))
    company = db.Column(db.String(140))
    last_seen = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)
    followed = db.relationship(
    'User',
    secondary=followers,
    primaryjoin=(followers.c.follower_id == id),
    secondaryjoin=(followers.c.followed_id == id),
    backref=db.backref('followers', lazy='dynamic'),
    lazy='dynamic')
def follow(self, user):
    if not self.is_following(user):
        self.followed.append(user)
def unfollow(self, user):
    if self.is_following(user):
        self.followed.remove(user)
def is_following(self, user):
    return self.followed.filter(
        followers.c.followed_id == user.id).count() > 0
def followed_posts(self):
    followed = Post.query.join(
        followers, (followers.c.followed_id == Post.user_id)).filter(
            followers.c.follower_id == self.id)
    own = Post.query.filter_by(user_id=self.id)
    return followed.union(own).order_by(Post.timestamp.desc())


class Post(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    body = db.Column(db.Text)
    timestamp = db.Column(db.DateTime, index=True, default=datetime.utcnow)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
def __repr__(self):
    return '<Post {}>'.format(self.body)
```

Comment: Google (or another) analytics library, not sure how you're displaying the CV but that's a good place to start. You can also roll your own, so whenever the file is accessed increment a counter. Hard to tell without more information.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `http GET` method to count each click and get the user data. For example if you had a model `Cv` that had an integer field `views` and a many to many field `viewers`:

```
@app.route('cv-view', methods=['GET'])
def cv_view(id):
    cv = Cv.query.get(id=id)
    if request.method == 'GET':
        cv.views += 1
        cv.viewers.add(current_user)
        db.session.commit()
        ... do more things ...
```

This will essentially call the function after the `GET` method everytime someone clicks a link.

**UPDATE**

Alright so in order to see all the requested info you will need to make a couple changes to your original `User` model. Firstly you will need to add 2 fields and a helper table like so:

**models.py**

```
viewers = db.Table('users', 
                       db.Column('viewed_id', db.Integer, 
                                 db.ForeignKey('user.id'), primary_key=True),
                       db.Column('viewer_id', db.Integer, 
                                 db.ForeignKey('user.id'), primary_key=True)


class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    # ... your fields ...
    views = db.Column(db.Integer(0))
    viewers = db.relationship('User', secondary=viewers, 
                              primaryjoin=id=viewers.c.viewed_id,
                              secondaryjoin=id=viewers.c.viewed_id,
                              lazy='subquery', backref=db.backref('viewed', lazy=True))
```

**routes.py**

```
@app.route('profile/<username>', methods=['GET'])
def profile(username):
    user = User.query.get(username=username)
    if request.method == 'GET':
        user.views += 1
        user.viewers.add(current_user)
        db.session.commit()
    # ...do more stuff maybe...
    return render_template('user.html', user=user)


@app.route('admin')
def admin():
    if not current_user.is_admin:
        return "this page is only for admins"
    else:
        users = User.query.all()
        return render_template('admin.html', users=users)
```

Then your template would look something like this:

**admin.html**

```
{% for user in users %}
    {{ user.username }} was viewed {{ user.views }} times by these users:
        {% for user in user.viewers %}
            {{ user.username }}
        {% endfor %}
<hr>
{% endfor %}
```

*P.S. You really should seperate your class methods with a blank line :)*

Comment: thanks so much, i wasnt expecting such a detailed answer! im really struggling with tying it all together. i have added the code i have, would it still be possible to use something like this?

Comment: @user1234567 let me get some things straight: in your admin site you want to see each user, how many times their profile was viewed and by which users it was viewed?

Comment: yes thats exactly it! i can show you the requiurments "he system should also provide an "admin" backend section for yourself which
will provide some rich information, for example number of times the CV has been seen,
number of times the CV has been downloaded, sortable and searchable list of contacts
who have accessed the CV". the Cv itself will just be another HTML page. There must be an Admin side to the application, available to administrators
only, showing a number of queries of the data in the database

Comment: @user1234567 I have updated my original answer

Comment: Wow this is amazing!! Thank you, I’m going to try it:)

Answer (score 0):

Try create an integer in the database that every time anyone creates a request, increase it by 1.